# Textbook on TVS that contains Theorem 32.2 about the completeness of the space of continuous linear maps

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

I have come across [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2176660/completeness-of-a-space-of-continuous-linear-maps-tvs) thread about TVS. The OP took below screenshot of **THEOREM 32.2.**

[image]

Could you please elaborate on the book from which the screenshot was taken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's at page 343 and in section 32 *Equicontinuous Sets of Linear Mappings* of Francois Treves's [Topological Vector Spaces, Distributions and Kernels](https://store.doverpublications.com/0486453529.html).